# After Ubuntu 18.04 update, dual-boot loads Windows 10 instead of grub. BIOS lets me access Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've got Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 running on my home PC, dual-boot setup with grub asking me which to choose at startup. Ran the usual updates on Ubuntu yesterday (not sure what was updated, though it was a hefty one). The update did ask whether I wanted to overwrite my edited grub file (I had previously increased the amount of seconds before it loaded Ubuntu, the default) with a newer version and I declined.

Well apparently that was the wrong choice because now the PC goes straight to Windows 10.

I can mash the <kbd>F11</kbd> key and enter the MSI boot menu, which lets me choose whether to load Windows or Ubuntu, so I do have access to both OSes, but obviously I'd like to get my menu back, without further breaking anything.

Comment: It probably was not the Ubuntu update, but a Windows update. Windows updates make Windows first in UEFI boot order. Going into UEFI (f2)can you not change UEFI boot order (not from UEFI boot menu, (often f10 or f12).

Comment: This fixed it! Hit F11 (it wasn't F2 to begin with, my bad) to enter the MSI boot menu, clicked on the boot order, then to hard drive BBS priorities, and could switch the order there. Saved configuration and it works now. Thank you!